# Set a field value with Go reflection of a non-pointer receiver interface implementation

Tags: go, reflection, interface

The goal is to set a new value of the `a.Stringer.Name` using Go reflection.

```golang
type A struct {
  Stringer fmt.Stringer
}

type MyStringer struct {
  Name string
}
func (m MyStringer) String() string {
  return m.Name
}

a := &A{
  Stringer: MyStringer {
    Name: "Adam",
  },
}

// The following code panics with: "reflect: reflect.Value.Set using unaddressable value"
reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem().
FieldByName("Stringer").Elem().
FieldByName("Name").Set(reflect.ValueOf("New name"))
```

Everything works fine with concrete types though:

```golang
type B struct {
  Stringer MyStringer
}

b := &B{
  Stringer: MyStringer {
    Name: "Adam",
  },
}

reflect.ValueOf(b).Elem().
FieldByName("Stringer").
FieldByName("Name").Set(reflect.ValueOf("New value"))
```

How to make the interface struct addressable? Am i missing something?

Comment: If you don't have a pointer to the `MyStringer`, then you can't addresses it, therefore you can't modify it in-place.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Take a look at the second block of code: MyStringer has no pointer and it is modifiable in-place.

Comment: Yes, you do have a pointer in the second value, because it's an addressable field of `B`, not an interface.

Comment: Is there any way to make `Stringer fmt.Stringer` addressable?

Comment: An interface itself can't make a value addressable, but you can make what you put in it addressable, by using a pointer.

Comment: >An interface can't be addressable; 

Could you please point me to some docs that explains this concept?

> but you can make what you put in it addressable, by using a pointer; 

yes this works

Comment: The dynamic value in an interface is not addressable by definition. Maybe this can help? https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection

Comment: I've read this post before posting the question here, unfortunately it does not explain unaddressability of interfaces. Will take a look there: https://research.swtch.com/interfaces
Thanks for help!